# Navigation button back button shows the same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, navigation

Attached are the snaps of a single view iPhone application that I created.  I have a segue from the Event cell to the second screen, the invitees list.  I have another segue from Invitees to the Checkin. So, when I go from Events to Invitees the navigation button shows Events, which is what I want. However, when I click on Lisa Webb cell, on the checkin the navigation button shows Lisa Webb.  When I click on the Lisa Webb navigation button I am shown the same checkin page but now the navigation button shows Event A, which is what I clicked on the Events list.  I want to show Invitees instead of Lisa Webb on the checkin page and then go back to the Invitees.  I cannot figure out how to do it.  I am using Navigation Controller.

[image: Events]

[image: Invitees]

[image: Checkin]

[image: Checkin after Lisa Webb button is clicked]

[image: Segues]

Below is the code I have for the prepareForSegue from Invitees(2nd) to the Checking(3rd)

```
#pragma mark - Segue
       -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"InviteesToCheckIn"]) {
            //UIViewController *inviteesViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
            CheckInViewController *checkInViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
            // In order to manipulate the destination view controller, another check on which table     (search or normal) is displayed is needed
            if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView      indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[filteredInviteesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] InviteeName];
            NSNumber *selectedInviteeId = [[filteredInviteesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] InviteeId];
            [checkInViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
            checkInViewController.inviteeId = selectedInviteeId;
        }
        else {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[theInvitees objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] InviteeName];
            NSNumber *selectedInviteeId = [[theInvitees objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] InviteeId];
            [checkInViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
            checkInViewController.inviteeId = selectedInviteeId;
        }

    }
}
```

## pragma mark - Table view delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"InviteesToCheckIn" sender:tableView];
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on from your description -- you need to more fully describe what you set up in IB. If you could post an image that shows your segues, that would be good.

Comment: I have added the image to the segues (5th pic)

Comment: I'm still confused about what's going on. Are you saying that when you're in the CheckInViewController (with title Lisa Webb and back button Lisa Webb), and you click on that back button, it takes you to another CheckInViewController scene with Lisa Webb as the title and Event A as the back button?

Comment: Yes that is what is occuring now.  What I want to do is when I go from Invitees(2nd) to Checking (3rd) I want the nav btn to show Invitees and the Title to show "LIsa Web"(or whichever) name I click. Now when I click on the name on Invitees I see Lisa Webb as the text in the nav and in the title.  When I click on the Lisa webb back btn I see another CheckIn but this time I see Event A as the text in the nav btn

Comment: It seems like you have 2 problems. You set the title to be InviteeName. Just don't do that. You should give each of the controllers the titles you want, like Invitees for the second controller, then don't do anything in CheckInController to set the title. But what doesn't make sense from what you've shown is how clicking on the back button in CheckInController takes you to another CheckInController. Are you doing any pushes, pops, etc. in code, or are you navigating only with the segues you show?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is the only other place in the InviteesTableViewController where i ref the segue "InviteesToCheckIn".  All the segues are of type push.  The segues are from the Cell.  Yeh, it doesnt make sense why I should see the other CheckIn when I click on the Lisa Web nav back btn.

Comment: You shouldn't have that code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath -- that, in combination with the segue will cause bad things to happen. You should put any code you need in prepareForSegue only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to change the previous title to literally "invitees" like you are saying then just set self.title = @"invitees" prior to the segue (prepareForSegue method). Then the navigation will show that on the next page for the back button. When you return (using an exit segue or pop you can set the title back to Event A or whatever you are requesting.

Comment: Hello Mark, I am setting the title of the next viewcontroller when I segue from Invitees to Checkin.  But that sets the nav button's text too (See pic 3).  I want the nav btn on 3rd pic to say Invitees and the title as the name i clicked on in the 2nd pic.

Comment: The back button title is set to the previous view controllers title. So if you are wanting to change that title you need to change the title of the previous view controller. If you are wanting the presented viewControllers text to be something else you need to set that from the prepareForSegue method in the previous controller. You can get a reference to the previous controller either by passing it in the prepareForSegue method or by accessing your navigation stack's viewControllers (1 view back).